# How to repopulate Facebook Sharing Dialog with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

What I'm trying to do is to make a form field that counts checked radio buttons with a specific value(integer 7). If the number of checked radio button is more than 3, then the system populates "Facebook" sharing dialog.

It works well if nothing goes wrong, but when I close the popup dialog, and click more radio buttons, even if the count is higher than 3, the Facebook dialog doesn't popup. I suspect that this is the problem due to initialization but I have no clue how to fix the issue. ( And because I suspect, I am not sure this guess is also directing me to the right solution )

The below is my javascript code to work this out.
I really hope to share any thought!

Best

```
<script>
  $(".evaluation").click(function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    var count = 0;
    $(".evaluation").each(function(index,item){
      if (item.value == 7){
        if (item.checked == true){
          count ++;
        }
      }
    });

    console.log('count:' + count);

    if (count >= 3){

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '####',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.5'
        });

        FB.ui({
      method: 'share_open_graph',
      action_type: 'og.likes',
      action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object:'http://www.###.com',
      })
    }, function(response){
      // Debug response (optional)
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }
  }

  );


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window.fbAsyncInit` and `FB.init` on Page load, one time. NOT on button click. Don't try to load and initialize the JavaScript SDK again, i assume the callback function will not get called because it is already initialized.

For example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: So I don't want fbAsyncInit pops up initially. I want it to be active once a certain condition has been met. Would you give me any tip to go there? (:

Comment: well, then use a boolean variable and set it to "true" after initializing the sdk...